# How can I add a common header for subpages in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a navigation bar system, and I want to know how I can make it so the subpage changes, but the header from the original page is still there. (I am using repl.it, just a heads-up).

I haven't put anything in folders yet.
I would also like to make it so that when I hover over the item with the “active” class (the one that is gray) it does not change colors.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&display=swap');

html body{
  background: #0E1212;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: none;
   font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

li {
  float: left;
}



li a {
  display: block;
  color: #DBDBDB;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

li a:hover {

  color: #682AE9;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


.active {
  color: #808080;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {color: #DBDBDB;}
  100% {color: #622cd8;)
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <script src='script.js'> </script>
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  


</head>
<body>

<ul id='menu'>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home" id="home">.home()</a></li>
  <li><a class="inactive" href="#news">.about()</a></li>
  <li><a class="inactive" href="#contact">.stuff()</a></li>
  <li><a class="inactive" href="#about">.apply()</a></li>
</ul>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the part of your question where you said to keep the color the same for the active class on hover, all I did was create another `@keyframe` so that at `0%` and `100%` they are both still the grey color. Then I used `transition: 0.5s;` to keep the animation for the color change smooth.

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&display=swap');
html body {
  background: #0E1212;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #DBDBDB;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #682AE9;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.active {
  color: #808080;
}

.active:hover {
  color: #808080;
}

@keyframes .active {
  0% {
    color: #808080;
  }
  100% {
    color: #808080;
    )
  }
 
  @keyframes example {
    0% {
      color: #DBDBDB;
    }
    100% {
      color: #622cd8;
      )
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <script src='script.js'>
  </script>
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>



  </head>

  <body>

    <ul id='menu'>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home" id="home">.home()</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="#news">.about()</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="#contact">.stuff()</a></li>
      <li><a class="inactive" href="#about">.apply()</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see when you hover over the first link (the active one) it is still grey and the others still work and turn purple with the `0.5s` time.